# Is there a clear rule when a woman should do the ghusl after menstruation or child-bed (nifas)?

Tags: salat, women, sawm, ghusl, menses

As a man and husband, I have no real idea about the menstruation, I mean what it feels like and if our sisters can feel it ending etc.

Now, for example, it happens that some of my female relatives know for example that her menstruation ended on a day "x" what if she did ghusl some days later? Because, for example, she had doubts whether it really ended! Should she make up the prayers/fast she missed from the moment her menstruation really ended or not?

Is there a clear rule when a woman should do the ghusl after menstruation or child-bed (nifas)?

Comment: May I know what is child bed? Also, I've heard, they need to  wait for some odd number of days before doing Ghusl. Please include this in your question asking if it's true.

Comment: See also: "[When should a woman perform Ghusl after her menses? - IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=174955)"

Comment: @Medi1Saif, as a relatively related site (of course if you are Turkish ...: http://www.islamquest.net/tr/archive/question/fa13087

Comment: Uh-huh, then I'm sorry ... God Bless You. Good luck.

Comment: @Shia_Sunni___________UNITY well i've read the Arabic version, but it seems to me more or less the opposite of my question. Because there the questioner is asking what to do if one prays after a too early washing/ghusl after menstruation! While in my question the woman is waiting a few days -maybe too long- to get certainty that her menstruation has ended!

Answer (score 1):

women has to do gusal on the day her menses end. if her menses ends on monday she has to take bath on same day, it is compulsory. if menses ended on monday and she take bath and after three or four day a drop come out the days between monday and those days also included in menstruation. salah and recietation of holy quran is not allowed in those days.

Reference:
https://islamqa.info/en/70438